# Yii2 Date compare validation

Tags: validation, date, yii2, compare-attribute

I have model rules() like below, but it is not working. It is showing error message always.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['start_date','end_date'], 'date', 'format' => 'php:F d Y'],
        ['start_date','compare','compareAttribute'=>'end_date','operator'=>'<'],
        ['end_date','compare','compareAttribute'=>'start_date','operator'=>'>'],
    ];
}
```

Comment: How can you compare these dates using this format ?...

Comment: yii2 validate class should parse the date.  some how i solved it.

Comment: you only need one compare attribute for both attributes. You need not compare `start_date` to `end_date` then repeat the comparison in the reverse order.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['start_date','end_date'], 'date', 'format' => 'php:F d Y'],
        ['start_date','validateDates'],
    ];
}


public function validateDates(){
    if(strtotime($this->end_date) <= strtotime($this->start_date)){
        $this->addError('start_date','Please give correct Start and End dates');
        $this->addError('end_date','Please give correct Start and End dates');
    }
}
```

you should write Client-Side Validation. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#client-side-validation

Comment: There is another way to do it: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/commit/1621f65545d24b03f80477aee286cf4be8e6faa4

Answer (score 9):

You can use default compare validation for this issue

```
['fromDate', 'date', 'timestampAttribute' => 'fromDate'],
['toDate', 'date','timestampAttribute' => 'toDate'],
['fromDate', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=> 'toDate', 'operator' => '<', 
'enableClientValidation' =>false],
```

[Yii compare validation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-core-validators#compare)

Comment: Nice solution, but need to remember about "format".

Comment: Also, if you use a consistent, reverse date format for each, such as 'format' => 'php:Y-m-d', then you don't need to specify timestampAttribute. If you do specify timestampAttribute, the default behaviour is to display the error but replace the date values that were input with their timestampAttributes, which is not very user-friendly.